# Default record page assignment in unlocked package: how to achieve that?

Tags: unlocked-package, flexipages, lightning-app-builder

It is possible to define default record page assignment in metadata of the standard or custom object.

However, if such metadata is included into unlocked package and installed, default record page assignment are ignored.

Why there is no error that such metadata is not supported?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like we have to deploy those with Metadata API deployments only and not as a part of unlocked packages installation.